# unknown format starting with '\000\005\026\007\000\002\000\000Mac OS X'

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I tried to search for an answer for this but cannot find one. I was playing with Tensorflow for image classification using retrain.py to retrain the inception library. It ran successfully on a Mac laptop. When I move all the files to a linux (CentOS 7) machine, it gives the error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\005\026\007\000\002\000\000Mac OS X'

Do the images come with hidden label from previous run on Mac OS X? If so, how do I convert it to linux format?

Thanks!

Comment: I looks like you have copied extra files from the Mac resource fork.  Use `ls -a` to find them.  This is a guess, but it seems reasonable given the circumstances. Delete(rm **filename** ) the extra file(s) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hex at the start matches the AppleDouble format (i.e. resource fork).

If your actual data files have resource forks (unlikely), you'd want to recover the content.

Or, some extra files have crept in (mac binaries, .DS_Store preview directory, etc), just delete those.

Magic number documented here: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle (jp)

> Unwanted "._" files can be removed using `dot_clean -m` on Mac OS X.